# Is it possible to create YAML from _within_ a dhall expression?

Tags: dhall

I would like to generate a ConfigMap for a service using dhall-kubernetes.  The service is configured using a YAML file.  I can use dhall to create the config in two passes:

```
$ dhall-to-yaml < server.dhall > server.yaml
$ dhall-to-yaml < configmap.dhall 
apiVersion: v1
data:
  server.yaml: |
    server:
      port: 8080
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
```

server.dhall:

```
let _config = { server.port = 8080 } in _config
```

configmap.dhall:

```
let kubernetes =
      ./package.dhall sha256:d9eac5668d5ed9cb3364c0a39721d4694e4247dad16d8a82827e4619ee1d6188

let _configMap1 =
      kubernetes.ConfigMap::{
      , metadata = kubernetes.ObjectMeta::{ name = "my-configmap" }
      , data = Some
        [ { mapKey = "server.yaml", mapValue = ./server.yaml as Text } ]
      }

in  _configMap1
```

package.dhall

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhall-lang/dhall-kubernetes/master/package.dhall
```

Is it possible to use only one invocation of dhall-to-yaml by generating the YAML from within dhall?  Something like this:

```
let kubernetes =
      ./package.dhall sha256:d9eac5668d5ed9cb3364c0a39721d4694e4247dad16d8a82827e4619ee1d6188

let _config = { server.port = 8080 }

let _configMap3 =
      kubernetes.ConfigMap::{
      , metadata = kubernetes.ObjectMeta::{ name = "my-configmap" }
      , data = Some
        [ { mapKey = "server.yaml"
          , mapValue = makeYAML _config -- make this work 
          }   
        ]   
      }   

in  _configMap3
```

I found the JSON.renderYAML function from the Prelude but this does not seem to be exactly what is needed.

Comment: Can you use a public URL for the `kubernetes` import, so I can reproduce your example?

Comment: Added the contents of package.dhall in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate YAML using `Prelude.JSON.renderYAML`, you first need to convert your config to the input `Prelude.JSON.Type` type. See the `makeJSON` function included in my version of `makeYAML` below:

```
let Prelude = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v15.0.0/package.dhall

let J = Prelude.JSON

let Config = { server : { port : Natural } }

let makeJSON
    : Config → J.Type
    =   λ(c : Config)
      → J.object
          ( toMap
              { server = J.object (toMap { port = J.natural c.server.port }) }
          )

let makeYAML
    : Config → Text
    = λ(c : Config) → J.renderYAML (makeJSON c)

let example =
      let _config
          : Config
          = { server.port = 8080 }

      in    assert
          :   makeYAML _config
            ≡ ''
              "server":
                "port": 8080
              ''

in  makeYAML
```

Comment: Thanks.  The issue with this is that I would then need to create a different makeJSON function for every dhall expression that I needed to convert.  It would be better to have a function that converts an arbitrary dhall expression to YAML similar to dhall-to-yaml.

Comment: Yeah. Such a function can't be defined in native Dhall though…

Comment: Yeah, this will be as close as you can get if you are implementing things within Dhall